# What is the process for purifying your home if you believe it may have been previously used for pagan worship?

Tags: avodah-zarah, sin, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, home-house, evil-resha

Locations of foreign worship are typically of concern. You're not supposed to enter a church for this very reason.

My question relates to the idea that one finds out their home was previously used for foreign worship. Say they discovered that they live in a home that was previously used by a pagan of some sort.

Assuming that moving wasn't an option, what would be the process of purifying the space as a Jewish home? Would simply living a Jewish life and restructuring the location for Jewish worship be enough?

> **Clarification:**
>
> ***In the example I'm giving, the house itself was not built specifically for idol worship or used as a formal location of idol
>   worship.  That being said, in the same way a Christian might light
>   candles at a shrine in their home, the house would have had foreign
>   worship occur within it.  That was the context of the example I was
>   giving.***

Comment: Was the house itself worshipped? Was it built for idol worship? Or was it just a regular house and someone decided to bring an idol into it? The Halacha is different in each of these cases.

Comment: @DonielF

Just clarified the example. That being said, I'd be interested in the context of each situation.

Comment: Congrats on HNQ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is explicitly addressed in Avodah Zarah 3:7:

> שְׁלשָׁה בָתִּים הֵן. בַּיִת שֶׁבָּנוּי מִתְּחִלָּה לַעֲבוֹדָה זָרָה, הֲרֵי זֶה אָסוּר. סִיְּדוֹ וְכִיְּרוֹ לַעֲבוֹדָה זָרָה וְחִדֵּשׁ, נוֹטֵל מַה שֶּׁחִדֵּשׁ. הִכְנִיס לְתוֹכָה עֲבוֹדָה זָרָה וְהוֹצִיאָהּ, הֲרֵי זֶה מֻתָּר.
>
> There are three houses: (1) A house which was initially built for idolatry, this is forbidden. (2) It was painted or plastered for idolatry, or [otherwise] it was renewed, he removes that which is new. (3) He brought an idol into it and removed it; this is permitted.

This Mishnah is accepted at face value by the Gemara (AZ 47b only adds that if the house itself was served, it's no different than a house built for idolatry), and we accordingly pasken like it (Rambam, Hil. Avodah Zarah 8:4; Tur, YD 145; Shulchan Aruch, YD 145:3).

Therefore, in your case, where the house was not built for idolatry, merely that idol worship occurred inside it, so long as the idols are removed, the house is permissible.

Comment: As a corollary, since we're not permitted to derive benefit from idol worship, would it be forbidden to sell a house that had been worshipped/built for idol worship? Would breaking even/selling at a loss make a difference?

Comment: @JoshK Pretty sure the answer is "no," but I don't have a hard source for that off th top of my head. Why don't you ask it separately, and I'll see if I can dig up the relevant halachos in the morning, B"N?