# Would you be permitted to sell a house that was built for idol worship?

Tags: avodah-zarah, business, home-house

Suppose you purchased a house and subsequently discovered it had been built for the express purpose of idol worship (a nice suburban Ba'al Peor temple right outside of Lakewood, say, or the Avodah Zarah or your choosing).

Now, as per BT Avodah Zarah 3:7 as quoted in this question,[What is the process for purifying your home if you believe it may have been previously used for pagan worship?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101410/what-is-the-process-for-purifying-your-home-if-you-believe-it-may-have-been-prev) such a home is forbidden.

We are also forbidden from deriving benefit from idol worship. Would one therefore be allowed to sell such a home? Would selling it at a break-even price or at a loss make a difference? Would a Torah Jew just be stuck with a home he couldn't live in, rent out, or sell for the rest of his life?